# Is it pythonic to check if a variable exists in the same if as first condition before evaluating the variable?

Tags: python

Is using short circuiting like this pythonic:

```
if variable is not None and variable > 2:
    do_something()
```

or something like this is better and more explicit?

```
try:
    if variable > 2:
        do_something()
except .......
```

Thank you

## edited

Added is not none

Comment: `if variable` does not check if a variable exists. Checking if a variable exists would be highly irregular, are you sure that is what you mean?

Comment: `try-except` can be reasonable, but *not* with a bare except clause.

Comment: The only reason you wouldn't know if `variable` exists or not is if you did something unorthodox like adding it to the `dict` returned by `globals`. Don't do that.

Comment: the more pythonic is `if variable is not None and variable > 2`, if I'm reading what you're trying to do correctly.  If you know the condition so easily like that a try except is overkill.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `if variable` check?  what do you mean by "check if a variable exists"?

Comment: @sturgemeister yes that is what i mean

Comment: Note that these two code blocks do different things. The latter would for example also "work" if `variable` were a `list`. It's not so much a question of what is Pythonic but of what you actually want to do.